# How could I make the program track the days completed on my habit tracker?

Tags: python

> I want to create a feature where the program will track the number of days the user has completed their habit. I attempted to do it below, but it only printed the integer 1, instead of adding up the days properly.

```
import click

names_file = open("names.txt", "r+")
habits_file = open("habits.txt", "r+")
habits_time = open("time.txt", "r+")
days_completed = + 1


# Welcome Message
print("Welcome to Habit Tracker by Synclare")

# User Info
if click.confirm('Are you a new user?', True):
   user_name = input("Welcome. What's your name? ")
   names_file.write(user_name)

   habit = input("\nEnter a habit: ")
   habits_file.write(habit)

   time = input("For how long do you want to do this habit?")
   habits_time.write(time)

   print("Habit created.")

   else:
           print("\nWelcome back, " + names_file.readline() + ".")
           if click.confirm('\nWould you like to view your current habits?', True):
           read_habit = habits_file.read()
           read_time = habits_time.read()
           print(read_habit + ": " + habits_time.read())

              if click.confirm("\nHave you completed today's habit?", True):
                  print("You have completed " + str(days_completed) + "/" + read_time)
```

Comment: are you storing `days_completed` in file? you are just using `days_completed = + 1` where do you defined `days_completed`?

Comment: I am not, although that did pop into my mind. I apologize this is my first coding project. I am new to python.

Comment: you can use json instead of text file. You can easily modify the values if you use  json.

Comment: How would you recommend doing this? Can I have an example of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the fact that you aren't storing the `days_completed`, you are also using:

`days_completed = +1`

Which does not update the variable (i.e. does not add 1 to `days_completed`). Use:

`days_completed += 1`

Or:

`days_completed = days_completed + 1`

This statement for now, only sets `days_completed` to `+1` (i.e. `1`).

Comment: Do you recommend I store the days_completed  in a text file?
Also, you cannot do days_completed = days_completed + 1

Comment: A text file could suffice. If you have a lot of information about each habit/part I would recommend using a .json file, and using the ```json``` module, as that would make it easy to organize and get the data.

Comment: Yes you can't. But it's because you haven't actually assigned anything to `days_completed`. Surely, you want to get the last `days_completed` value from the file, and update it (i.e. add `1` to it)?

Comment: Could you write out an example?

Comment: Sure. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you read days_completed from file. I would suggest to create some kind of data structures for habits - at least dictionary. Also it is not clear what do you mean by time - days repeated, or total time in minutes.
Something like:

```
total_time = 6

habbits = {
    'habbit1': {'time': total_time},
    'habbit2': {'time': total_time}
    }

for h in habbits:
    print(f'For {h} you have spent {habbits[h]["time"]}')
```

Comment: Yes, I mean how many days you have completed the habit. 
Also, I tried the code you suggested it got several errors.

Comment: Sorry, there were some typos in f-string

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the concept (no error check, no functions):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    habits = {
        'Habit1': {'days': 1},
        'Habit2': {'days': 5}
        }

    print('You have following habits:')
    for index, habit in enumerate(habits, 1):
        print(f'{index}. {habit} - {habits[habit]["days"]} day(s)')

    i = int(input(f'Select habit to increment (1 - {len(habits)}): '))
    habit_from_input = list(habits.keys())[i-1]
    habits[habit_from_input]['days'] += 1

    print('You have following habits:')
    for index, habit in enumerate(habits, 1):
        print(f'{index}. {habit} - {habits[habit]["days"]} day(s)')
```